# Constant-time index for string column on Oracle database

Tags: oracle, database-design, indexing, hashmap, database-performance

I have an orders table. The table belongs to a multi-tenant application, so there are orders from several merchants in the same table. The table stores hundreds of millions of records. There are two relevant columns for this question:

- **MerchantID**, an integer storing the merchant's unique ID
- **TransactionID**, a string identifying the transaction

I want to know whether there is an efficient index to do the following:

- Enforce a unique constraint on **Transaction ID** for each **Merchant ID**. The constraint should be enforced in *constant time*.
- Do *constant time* queries involving *exact* matches on both columns (for instance, `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE TransactionID = 'ff089f89feaac87b98a' AND MerchantID = 24`)

Further info:

1. I am using Oracle 11g. Maybe [this Oracle article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/hash003.htm) is relevant to my question?
2. I cannot change the column's data type.
3. *constant time* means an index performing in O(1) time complexity. Like a hashmap.

Comment: Create an ordinary index on `merchantid, transactionid`? I suspect you're massively overthinking this...

Comment: @Ben, do ordinary indexes work in constant time? I edited the question to show the need for constant-time: I have several hundred million records stored on the table.

Comment: What do you mean by "constant time"?

Comment: @Boneist I mean O(1) time complexity

Comment: In addition to what @Ben suggested, I'd create a unique constraint on the merchantid and transactionid columns. An index would then be created to support the constrain (and depending on how you created the constraint - deferred, nonvalidated etc - it may be unique or non-unique).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your reason for needing the O(1) time complexity requirement?

Comment: @Boneist several hundred million records on the table.

Comment: A straight-forward vanilla unique constraint as @Boneist suggests is what you need and nothing would perform better than that.  The "constant time" requirement you mention is more-or-less given by standard B-tree indexes since the number of levels grows logarithmically, so it never takes more than a handful of reads to reach your single row of data.

Comment: That's not a reason though; do you have a time limit on how long it can take to request rows in your `merchantid = :val1 and transactionid = :val2` type queries? Also, have you tried creating the bog-standard constraint (and index), and timed how long it takes?

Comment: @Boneist I wish I was allowed to upvote a comment more than once!

Comment: @TonyAndrews that is not constant time. The tree height grows proportional to log(n), where n is the number of records it holds.

Comment: Yes that it what I said.  Are you saying you'd be happier if the b-tree index always had e..g 7 levels even when there were only a few rows?  It seems to me that your concern is misguided. As @Boneist has said, what happens when you try a b-tree index on your table?

Comment: @TonyAndrews what I'm saying is that it is impossible using a b-tree. The index should use something like a hashtable.

Comment: So you keep saying - but *why*?

Comment: Is this an academic question or is there a real business requirement here? Tables with hundreds of millions of rows are not uncommon in serious Oracle databases, but b-tree indexes are generally considered to be more than adequate to implement unique constraints and indexes.

Comment: [Bitmap index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#i7495). Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis - for a unique constraint?!

Comment: I have a table in my Dev environment with 3M rows and its unique b-tree index has a depth of 2.  If it was 100 times bigger (300M rows) the level would probably increase to 3.  Is that a big deal?

Comment: @TonyAndrews that sounds good! But does the B-tree you mention include a string column?

Comment: Why don't you try creating the constraint + index on your table and see for yourself? I can honestly say that I have never needed to worry about whether an index lookup was "constant time" before; especially since you'll most likely have bigger issues to think about such as logical vs physical IO (your index may well be cached, but your table is unlikely to be, unless you're querying for data that's in a small enough set of blocks).

Comment: My index is on a VARCHAR2(10) column

Comment: You could try comparing the performance of an ordinary b-tree index vs. a hash cluster, but I suspect you're suffering from the XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - i.e. what is more important - that your solution is O(1) or that it performs well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hash clusters can provide O(1) access time, but not O(1) constraint enforcement time.  However, in practice the constant access time of a hash cluster is worse than the O(log N) access time of a regular b-tree index.  Also, clusters are more difficult to configure and do not scale well for some operations.

**Create Hash Cluster**

```
drop table orders_cluster;
drop cluster cluster1;

create cluster cluster1
(
    MerchantID number,
    TransactionID varchar2(20)
)
single table hashkeys 10000; --This number is important, choose wisely!

create table orders_cluster
(
    id number,
    MerchantID number,
    TransactionID varchar2(20)
) cluster cluster1(merchantid, transactionid);

--Add 1 million rows.  20 seconds.
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10 loop
        insert into orders_cluster
        select rownum + i * 100000, mod(level, 100)+ i * 100000, level
        from dual connect by level <= 100000;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/

create unique index orders_cluster_idx on orders_cluster(merchantid, transactionid);

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'ORDERS_CLUSTER');
end;
/
```

**Create Regular Table (For Comparison)**

```
drop table orders_table;

create table orders_table
(
    id number,
    MerchantID number,
    TransactionID varchar2(20)
) nologging;

--Add 1 million rows.  2 seconds.
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10 loop
        insert into orders_table
        select rownum + i * 100000, mod(level, 100)+ i * 100000, level
        from dual connect by level <= 100000;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/

create unique index orders_table_idx on orders_table(merchantid, transactionid);

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'ORDERS_TABLE');
end;
/
```

**Trace Example**

SQL*Plus Autotrace is a quick way to find the explain plan and track I/O activity per statement.  The number of I/O requests is labeled as "consistent gets" and is a decent way of measuring the amount of work done.  This code demonstrates how the numbers were generated for other sections.  The queries often need to be run more than once to warm things up.

```
SQL> set autotrace on;
SQL> select * from orders_cluster where merchantid = 100001 and transactionid = '2';

no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 621801084

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS HASH| ORDERS_CLUSTER |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("MERCHANTID"=100001 AND "TRANSACTIONID"='2')


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         31  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        485  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        540  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          1  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          0  rows processed

SQL>
```

**Find Optimal Hashkeys, Trade-Offs**

For optimal read performance all the hash collisions should fit in one block (all Oracle I/O is done per block, usually 8K).  Getting the ideal storage right is tricky and requires knowing the hash algorithm, storage size (not the same as the block size), and number of hash keys (the buckets).  Oracle has a default algorithm and size so it is possible to focus on only one attribute, the number of hash keys.

More hash keys leads to fewer collisions.  This is good for TABLE ACCESS HASH performance as there is only one block to read.  Below are the number of consistent gets for different hashkey sizes.  For comparison an index access is also included.  With enough hashkeys the number of blocks decreases to the optimal number, 1.

```
Method          Consistent Gets (for transactionid = 1, 20, 300, 4000, and 50000)
Index           4,  3,  3,  3,  3
Hashkeys 100    1, 31, 31, 31, 31
Hashkeys 1000   1,  3,  4,  4,  4
Hashkeys 10000  1,  1,  1,  1,  1
```

More hash keys also lead to more buckets, more wasted space, and a slower TABLE ACCESS FULL operation.

```
Table type      Space in MB
HeapTable       24MB
Hashkeys 100    26MB
hashkeys 1000   30MB
hashkeys 10000  81MB
```

To reproduce my results, use a sample query like `select * from orders_cluster where merchantid = 100001 and transactionid = '1';` and change the last value to 1, 20, 300, 4000, and 50000.

**Performance Comparison**

Consistent gets are predictable and easy to measure, but at the end of the day only the wall clock time matters.  Surprisingly, the index access with 4 times more
 consistent gets is still faster than the optimal hash cluster scenario.

```
--3.5 seconds for b-tree access.
declare
    v_count number;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        select count(*)
        into v_count
        from orders_table
        where merchantid = 100000 and transactionid = '1';
    end loop;
end;
/

--3.8 seconds for hash cluster access.
declare
    v_count number;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        select count(*)
        into v_count
        from orders_cluster
        where merchantid = 100000 and transactionid = '1';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

I also tried the test with variable predicates but the results were similar.

**Does it Scale?**

No, hash clusters do not scale.  Despite the O(1) time complexity of TABLE ACCESS HASH, and the O(log n) time complexity of INDEX UNIQUE SCAN, hash clusters never seem to outperform b-tree indexes.

I tried the above sample code with 10 million rows.  The hash cluster was painfully slow to load, and still under-performed the index on SELECT performance.  I tried to scale it up to 100 million rows but the insert was going to take 11 days.

The good news is that b*trees scale well.  Adding 100 million rows to the above example only require 3 levels in the index.  I looked at all `DBA_INDEXES` for a large database environment (hundreds of databases and a petabyte of data) - the worst index had only 7 levels.  And that was a pathological index on `VARCHAR2(4000)` columns.  In most cases your b-tree indexes will stay shallow regardless of the table size.

In this case, O(log n) beats O(1).

**But WHY?**

Poor hash cluster performance is perhaps a victim of Oracle's attempt to simplify things and hide the kind of details necessary to make a hash cluster work well.  Clusters are difficult to setup and use properly and would rarely provide a significant benefit anyway.  Oracle has not put a lot of effort into them in the past few decades.

The commenters are correct that a simple b-tree index is best.  But it's not obvious why that should be true and it's good to think about the algorithms used in the database.