# Query that can benefit from index, cluster or hash-cluster

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, database-performance

I'm trying to find equi-join query that shows a decent performance bump when I use an index, cluster or hash-cluster structure on my data. I initially need to run the query on unstructured data first and the execution time should be significant so that I can see a performance boost with any of the 3 structures. The issues I am having is that if I use a query that utilizes an index column the search is too narrow and so I get too few rows returned and then my baseline query's execution time is too fast so I can't measure the time later.

It seems the only queries that have any major effect on my baseline queries execution time are those that cause a full table scan of the table with the most rows, but then that makes using an index structure useless as it won't use the index. Do clusters or hash-clusters benefit from full table scans - in general I don't know what queries benefit from clusters/hash-clusters.

My table has 500,000+ rows and some of the queries I have tried:

```
SELECT c.Cust_name, s.total_price
  FROM Sales s, Customer c
 WHERE s.Cust_id = c.Cust_id
 ORDER BY c.Cust_name;


SELECT count(*)
  FROM Sales s, Customer c 
 WHERE s.Cust_id < 500
   AND s.Cust_id = c.Cust_id;


SELECT c.Cust_name, s.total_price
 FROM Sales s, Customer c
WHERE s.Cust_id = c.Cust_id
  AND c.Cust_name LIKE '%A';
```

Comment: What indexes are on the tables? Have you calculated the table statistics ?

Answer (score 0):

Meaningful database performance testing requires multiple runs, alternating between different methods, removing the outliers, and averaging the remaining values.  This is necessary to avoid differences caused by caching and server load fluctuations.

Something like this will work in SQL*Plus.  It could be automated more in PL/SQL but would take more code.

```
set timing on;

--Run #1:
declare
    v_count number;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100 loop
        SELECT count(*) into v_count
        from Sales s, Customer c
        WHERE s.Cust_id < 500 AND s.Cust_id = c.Cust_id;
    end loop;
end;
/

--Run #2:
alter table ... (changesomething here)

declare
    v_count number;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100 loop
        SELECT count(*) into v_count
        from Sales s, Customer c
        WHERE s.Cust_id < 500 AND s.Cust_id = c.Cust_id;
    end loop;
end;
/

--Run #1:
...
```

If you really need to use a single run of a query to demonstrate these differences, you'll need to make the data larger and make the queries more selective.  Index range scans are generally only helpful when they select a small percentage of data from the table.  The magic number depends on a lot of factors, like how fast is single-block versus multi-block I/O on the hardware, how ordered is the index (the index clustering factor), etc.

My experience with hash clusters has been [disappointing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32071259/409172).  I think that feature is only around for historical purposes; I almost never see them discussed in Oracle performance tuning resources.  Nobody has the time to figure out *exactly* how their data will fit into blocks.